# Google Script - Copy Data from sheet 1 to sheet 2 including Notes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I don't find the solution to copy notes with the content of each cell, from sheet "Origin" to sheet "Copy".
Here after le link to a sample spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ilJ5y20jZkEMbwjYbu1jcEXe8-p2-2goUBaEK4jVdPU/edit?usp=sharing

The code that I've written is after and runs correctly only for the values without note :

```
    function CopyData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

// List of Sheets to copy
  let shXXX = ss.getSheetByName("Origin");



// List of Sheets to paste
  let destXXX = ss.getSheetByName("Copy");


//Array if column is filled
let shXXXfilled = shXXX.getRange('A2:E').getValues();



let arrayToCopy = []

for(let i = 0; i < shXXXfilled.length; i++)
if(shXXXfilled[i][5] != ""){
  Logger.log(shXXXfilled[i][5])
arrayToCopy.push(shXXXfilled[i])

}
  Logger.log(arrayToCopy)
destXXX.getRange(destXXX.getLastRow()+1, 1 , arrayToCopy.length , 5 ).setValues(arrayToCopy);



}
```

If you have idea to improve the content of it, your recommandation will be welcomed because I am not very good in coding.
Thanks a lot.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Copy all rows from range

Try this optimized code that copies **whole range** of data into sheet in same spreadsheet (with notes etc):

```
function CopyData()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // sheet copy from
  let sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet11');
  // copy starting from second row
  let sourceStartRow = 2;
  // copy starting from first column
  let sourceStartCol = 1;
  let sourceEndRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  let sourceEndCol = sourceSheet.getLastColumn();

  // calculate number of rows and columns in source range
  let sourceNumRows = sourceEndRow - sourceStartRow + 1;
  let sourceNumCols = sourceEndCol - sourceStartCol + 1;

  // get source range
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(sourceStartRow, sourceStartCol, sourceNumRows, sourceNumCols);


  // sheet copy to
  let destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet12');
  // copy to sheet starting from next empty row
  let destStartRow = destSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  // copy to sheet starting from first column
  let destStartCol = 1;

  // calculate number of rows and columns copied to destination range
  // count of rows and columns should be the same as in source range
  let destNumRows = sourceNumRows;
  let destNumCols = sourceNumCols;

  // get destination range
  let destRange = destSheet.getRange(destStartRow, destStartCol, destNumRows, destNumCols);

  // copy source range to destination range with notes
  sourceRange.copyTo(destRange);
}
```

Before:

Source: [image]

Destination: [image]

After:

[image]

If run function again it will append data starting from next empty row:

[image]

---

### 2. Copy only non-empty rows from range

According to feedback:

> Hi and thank you for your quick reply. your code runs and copy paste the values and notes coorectly but in my original code, I've integrating a loop in order to exclude the lines which are empty in column 5 of the original sheet and copy in the last line of the destination sheet. Is it possible to integrate it in your code?

added version that copies only **non-empty rows** from source range:

```
function copyDataOnlyNonEmptyRows()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // sheet copy from
  let sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet11');
  // copy starting from second row
  let sourceStartRow = 2;
  // copy starting from first column
  let sourceStartCol = 1;
  let sourceEndRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  let sourceEndCol = sourceSheet.getLastColumn();

  // calculate number of rows and columns in source range
  let sourceNumRows = sourceEndRow - sourceStartRow + 1;
  let sourceNumCols = sourceEndCol - sourceStartCol + 1;

  // get source range
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(sourceStartRow, sourceStartCol, sourceNumRows, sourceNumCols);

  // get values to find out which rows are empty
  let sourceValues = sourceRange.getDisplayValues();



  // sheet copy to
  let destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet12');
  // copy to sheet starting from first column
  let destStartCol = 1;



  let sourceBatchStartRow = undefined;
  let sourceBatchEndRow = undefined;
  for (let i = 0; i < sourceNumRows; i++)
  {
    let row = sourceValues[i];

    let rowNum = sourceStartRow + i;

    console.log(row, 'row is empty:', isRowEmpty(row));

    // check if row is empty
    let rowIsEmpty = isRowEmpty(row);
    let rowIsLast = i === sourceNumRows - 1;
    // special case for last row
    // need to include it in batch *before* current iteration ends so last batch is actually copied
    if (rowIsLast)
    {
      // if there is no previously started batch of non empty rows
      if (sourceBatchStartRow === undefined)
      {
        // start new batch with current row
        sourceBatchStartRow = rowNum;
        sourceBatchEndRow = rowNum;
        console.log('updating batch to', sourceBatchStartRow, sourceBatchEndRow);
      }
      else
      {
        // update batch to include current row
        sourceBatchEndRow = rowNum;
        console.log('updating batch end to', sourceBatchEndRow);
      }
    }


    // if row is empty or last, time to copy existing batch
    if (rowIsEmpty || rowIsLast)
    {
      // if there is any batch defined, copy it
      if (sourceBatchStartRow !== undefined && sourceBatchEndRow !== undefined)
      {
        console.log('copying previous batch', sourceBatchStartRow, sourceBatchEndRow);

        // copy starting from first column
        let sourceBatchStartCol = sourceStartCol;

        // calculate number of rows and columns in source range
        let sourceBatchNumRows = sourceBatchEndRow - sourceBatchStartRow + 1;
        let sourceBatchNumCols = sourceNumCols;

        let sourceBatchRange = sourceSheet.getRange(sourceBatchStartRow, sourceBatchStartCol, sourceBatchNumRows, sourceBatchNumCols);


        // copy to sheet starting from next empty row
        let destBatchStartRow = destSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
        // copy to sheet starting from first column
        let destBatchStartCol = destStartCol;

        // calculate number of rows and columns copied to destination range
        // count of rows and columns should be the same as in source range
        let destBatchNumRows = sourceBatchNumRows;
        let destBatchNumCols = sourceBatchNumCols;

        // get destination range
        let destBatchRange = destSheet.getRange(destBatchStartRow, destBatchStartCol, destBatchNumRows, destBatchNumCols);

        // copy source range to destination range with notes
        sourceBatchRange.copyTo(destBatchRange);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();

        // reset batch
        sourceBatchStartRow = undefined;
        sourceBatchEndRow = undefined;
        console.log('reset batch', sourceBatchStartRow, sourceBatchEndRow);
      }
    }
    // if row is not empty, continue working with batch
    else if (!rowIsEmpty)
    {
      // if there is no previously started batch of non empty rows
      if (sourceBatchStartRow === undefined)
      {
        // start new batch with current row
        sourceBatchStartRow = rowNum;
        sourceBatchEndRow = rowNum;
        console.log('updating batch to', sourceBatchStartRow, sourceBatchEndRow);
      }
      else
      {
        // update batch to include current row
        sourceBatchEndRow = rowNum;
        console.log('updating batch end to', sourceBatchEndRow);
      }
    }
  }
}

function isRowEmpty(row)
{
  return row
    // trim values
    .map(el => el.trim())
    // check there is no non-empty values
    .every(el => !el);
}
```

Before:

Source: [image]

Destination: [image]

After:

[image]

If you run function again, it will add new rows starting from next empty row:

[image]

Comment: Hi and thank you for your quick reply. your code runs and copy paste the values and notes coorectly but in my original code, I've integrating a loop in order to exclude the lines which are empty in column 5 of the original sheet and copy in the last line of the destination sheet. Is it possible to integrate it in your code?

Comment: I updated answer based on empty rows exclusion